# add class "last" to every div number 4 , 8 , 12 , 16 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to add class "last" to every div number 4 , 8 , 12 , 16 etc .
i think this is not big problem right ?

Before :

```
<div id="main">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
</div>
```

After

```
<div id="main">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div class="last">Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div class="last">Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div class="last">Element 12</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your markup really will be *only* `div` elements, then [F. Calderan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10681150/157247) is the way to go.

If you may also have other elements in there and you want to ignore those, you'd do this:

```
$("#main > div").filter(function(index) {
  return index % 4 === 3;
}).addClass("last");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uliqep) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uliqep/edit)

That's because even though `div:nth-child(4n)` *looks like* it means every four divs, it doesn't; it means divs that are the 4th, 8th, etc. element in their parent container. So if you throw others in there, it won't work.

But again, if you only have `div`s, F's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#main > div:nth-child(4n)').addClass('last');
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7fE6/

Note: if you have to apply some style to those elements (and you're not supporting IE8 or previous IE browsers) you could simply define that selector into your CSS, e.g.

```
 #main > div:nth-child(4n) {
     /* supported by IE9+ and all modern browser */
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#main div').each(function(e){
     if((e+1) % 4 == 0){
         $(this).addClass('last');
     }
 });
})
​
```

here is the running example

[Find the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mHp/1/)

hope it helped...